# Пароль через CreateFile для PhysicalDrive1

Tags: c++, windows, password

Возможно ли через функцию CreateFile установить пароль на PhysicalDrive1, т.е. на само устройство, а не на тома? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Comment: О каком пароле идет речь, поясните. Пока что на ваш вопрос ответить нельзя.

Comment: О пароле на самом жестком диске. На устройстве, а не на файловой системе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя функцией `CreateFile` (самой по себе) нельзя отправить АТА-команду, ее можно отправить запросом [IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559309(v=vs.85).aspx) через функцию `DeviceIoControl` (которой в качестве аргумента передается дескриптор, возвращенный как раз функцией CreateFile).

Для выполнения команды нужно передать с ioctl-запросом структуру ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX с заполненными полями: `CurrentTaskFile` (состояние регистров на входе), `DataBufferOffset` (смещение блока данных) и др., а за ней - блок данных определенного формата, содержащий аргументы команды. Информацию о необходимых значениях регистров и формате команды установки пароля можно найти в [документации по АТА-командам](http://www.t13.org/documents/uploadeddocuments/docs2006/d1699r3f-ata8-acs.pdf).

**Примечание.** Windows начиная с Vista и XP SP3 при загрузке посылает команду SECURITY FREEZE LOCK всем жестким дискам, работающим под стандартным ATA-драйвером, поэтому выполнить изменение пароля и другие подобные действия не выйдет. Для решения этой проблемы можно запускать программу под более старой ОС или [Windows 8 Preinstallation Environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/security-group-commands), которые не посылают данную команду. Также SECURITY FREEZE LOCK может посылаться некоторыми BIOS при инициализации системы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Подскажите еще, по поводу драйвера: какие использовать библиотеки/функции/классы использовать, чтобы реализовать такой драйвер?

И по поводу WinPE: Как именно с ним работать? (ATA команды и Freeze lock)

Answer (score 0):

Через функцию CreateFile задать пароль на HDD нельзя. Пароль задается ATA-командой SECURITY SET PASSWORD, CreateFile не для отправки ATA-команд.

Comment: Тогда когда через эту ATA-команду можно установить пароль, чтобы еще и быть в Kernel mode?

Comment: @nico1st Да, тогда когда

Comment: Тогда как*, (переутомился и немного не соображаю)

Comment: @nico1st А при чем тут CreateFile?

Comment: Наткнулся на вопрос, на каком-то английском форуме, где был ответ, что через CreateFile можно было поставить пароль, поэтому и решил поинтересоваться тут об этом

Comment: Почему бы вам не почитать MSDN про указанную функцию и не спросить на том форуме, как же это они так умудрились-то?